# Trouble with wording of this math question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

"Find the derivative as follows (you need not simplify)":

a) $y = 2^x f (x)$, where $f (x)$ is a differentiable function and so is $f '(x)$: find $\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$.

That's the exact wording of the question, and no additional information is given outside of this question.  Can anyone make sense out of this question? I'm not looking for a solved answer, just an idea of what I'm actually supposed to be doing. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you're actually supposed to find $d^2y/dy^2$.  In that case, you can find that derivative using the product rule and $f(x),f'(x),f''(x)$ where appropriate.

Comment: Are you familiar with implicit differentiation?

Comment: It was introduced in class recently - guess I need to look into that subject. What really confuses me is why y = 2^x is being multiplied by f(x) when I don't even know what f(x) is.

Comment: @user70228 they don't expect you to simplify -- you may write $f, f', f''$.

Comment: Oh, wow. That makes more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @user70228 not a problem! When you finish, I can check your answer for you.

Comment: @oldrinb Not sure if I did this correctly but here is my process:  
  
y = 2^x * f(x)  

Y' = 2^x(log2 f(x) + 2^x f'(x)  

y'' = 2^x (f''(x) + log4 f'(x) + log^2(2) f(x))  
  
I hope you can read that coherently, I'm not sure how to use math formatting on here.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Comment: @Frank:  How about $d^2y/dx^2$ instead?

Answer (score 5):

We are given:

$$y = 2^x f(x)$$

where $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are differentiable functions and asked to find the second derivative.

This is just an application of the product rule, so

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \left(2^x f(x)\right) = 2^x (f(x) \log(2) + f'(x))$

$\displaystyle \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left(2^x f(x)\right) = 2^x (f(x) log(2)^2 + 2\log(2) f'(x) + f''(x))$